# Bitwise Operations Java - Long to Binary

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, long-integer, bit-shift

I found this code for an arithmetic encoder and I'm a bit confused as to where the values mentioned in the comments are coming from.

Can anyone go through whats happening in these operations step by step?

```
protected final long STATE_SIZE  = 32;  // Number of bits for 'low' and 'high'. Must be in the range [1, 62] (and possibly more restricted).
    protected final long MASK        = (1L << (STATE_SIZE - 0)) - 1;  //  111...111, all ones
```

These are my assumptions so far:

- "MASK" is defining a Long which is set to 1
- Then shifting this by 32 (I thought) would give 100000...00 (which I have verified myself in java.
- Then I get stuck. **I'm not sure how the "-1" makes them all change to 1's**?

I've tried it out myself using this code:

```
long STATE_SIZE  = 32;
        long shifted = 1L << STATE_SIZE-0;
        long shiftedMinusOne = shifted -1;
        System.out.println("Shifted: " + shifted);
        System.out.println("Shifted Minus One: " + shiftedMinusOne);
        System.out.println("Shifted Binary: " + Long.toBinaryString(shifted));
        System.out.println("Shifted Minus One Binary: " + Long.toBinaryString(shiftedMinusOne));
```

And my output is:

```
Shifted: 4294967296
Shifted Minus One: 4294967295
Shifted Binary: 100000000000000000000000000000000
Shifted Minus One Binary: 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Could anyone tell me if I'm doing something wrong or why the -1 makes them all 1's?

Comment: did any of the answers answer you question?

Comment: I just realized how stupid that question was. I got so wrapped up in what I was doing that I over complicated the simplest thing. Thanks to everyone that answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you realize that the binary operation is:

```
 100000000000000000000000000000000 - 000000000000000000000000000000001 
  = 011111111111111111111111111111111
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note the difference in length:

```
  100000000000000000000000000000000 - 1
=  11111111111111111111111111111111
```

This is a correct binary subtraction. You are doing okay :)

Answer (score 2):

The `-1` changes binary `10000` to `1111` for the same reason that it changes

- decimal `10000` to `9999` or
- hex `10000` to `ffff` or
- octal `10000` to `7777`.

Binary ist just another number representation that happens to have only two digits.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with what you are doing...

4294967296 = 2^32

The number series: 100000000000000000000000000000000 = 4294967296   (34 digits)

The number series: 11111111111111111111111111111111  = 4294967295   (33 digits)

If you understand how numbers are represented in binary then this should clear it up.

Also I believe the idea of the MASK is so that you have a series of 111111....s to bitwise AND or bitwise OR with other numbers to do nifty maths.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

4294967296 = 2^32 = 100000000000000000000000000000000 (bit 32 is set)
4294967295 = 2^31+2^30 ... + 2^1 + 2^0 (bits 0 to 31 are set)

Answer (score 1):

simple.

Binary value of `4294967295` is `11111111111111111111111111111111`

Ref [Decimal to Binary conversion](http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Binary).